# Android volley singleton for JSON and image

Tags: singleton, android-volley

Intially i was using volley mainly for JSONObject. the following was my singleton

```
package com.simha.yatras;

import android.app.Application;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getReqQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {

        getReqQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req) {

        getReqQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingReq(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to use volley for bitmap imagerequest. I want the images to be cached so that i need not load them everytime.

So what should be the singleton code be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Volley provide ImageRequest class:

```
ImageView mImageView;
String url = "http://i.imgur.com/7spzG.png";
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);

// Retrieves an image specified by the URL, displays it in the UI.
ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(url,
new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}, 0, 0, null,
   new Response.ErrorListener() {
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_load_error);
    }
   });
// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);## Heading ##
```